# Android: Enumerate all wake locks in the system

Tags: android

I have trouble with an Android app keeping a partial wake lock on my system; so I'd like to write an app that keeps an eye on the bad app and kills its partial wake lock shortly after it acquires one.

[android.os.PowerManager](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java&q=android.os.PowerManager&d=4) is used to acquire and release wake locks but I don't see any way to get all wake locks in the system; even if I got access to its `IPowerManager mService` variable, that service doesn't release a wake lock without the `IBinder` object associated with the wake lock.

So I'm stuck. How do I proceed? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, in that you cannot write an app that cancels another app's `WakeLocks`.

FWIW, you can use `adb shell dumpsys` to find out about outstanding `WakeLocks`, among other things.

Comment: Luckily yesterday, after even more searching about the bug in the app that holds the wakelock, I found a workaround to get it to stop. Thanks for the dumpsys trick though, that's pretty cool!

Comment: Another way to see wakelocks is
`adb shell cat /proc/wakelocks`